# Full Text search engine other than Lucene Search text

Tags: full-text-search

I need a full text search engine which should support internationalization.

Thanks

Comment: Internationalization? Do you mean you want support for non-English languages?

Comment: Also: why "other than Lucene"? Because you already know Lucene and want to see alternatives, or are you having some issues?

Answer (score 2):

Use Sphinx with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

There is one called [Xapian](http://xapian.org/). I haven't used it but I've heard good things.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Ferret ( Ruby ) and worked for me, unfortunately it only works in ruby 1.8.x , (It's not supported in Ruby 1.9) 
Other solutions were already mentioned: Sphinx, Xapian , also SolR ( based on Java/Lucene) should work)

Answer (score 0):

an old yet good reference.

http://wrg.upf.edu/WRG/dctos/Middleton-Baeza.pdf